# Visual Studio 2015 XAML designer not showing with System.Runtime.Remoting.RemotingException

Tags: visual-studio, windows-store-apps, visual-studio-2015, xaml-designer

My problem is with my XAML designer in vs 2015 community edition on my windows 10. it simply does not load. XAML designer on WPF desktop app works fine. 
[VS 2015 xaml designer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sgml4.jpg)

An unhandled exception has occurred
  System.Runtime.Remoting.RemotingException
  [3332] Designer process terminated unexpectedly!

The catch is I currently have vs 2013 pro on the same OS(windows 10) and it loads XAML designer perfectly for windows 8.1 apps.
  I have to emphasise that on vs 2015 both windows store app for **windows 10** and **windows 8.1** fail to load XAML designer. Also, the application runs perfectly when you build and run the program. it is just the XAML designer.

The target version and min version are matched on 10240 for windows 10 app store.
  Here is the picture of my XAML designer for windows 8.1 on **vs 2013 pro**
[vs 2013 XAML designer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1of2L.jpg)

- Developer mode is on
- i reinstalled vs 2015
- Windows 10 is updated
- VS 2015 with update 1 is running

Comment: This seems to be a pretty common problem. I started getting the same error and came across this question searching for any resolutions. I have tried all of the standard fixes as well as you mentioned above, in addition to cleared the shadow cache: `C:\Users\[user]\AppData\Microsoft\VisualStudio\14.0\Designer\ShadowCache` but haven't had any luck. The program itself works fine, just the designer is borked. :(